# Fail to dump large size sql in phpmyadmin. Where to set PHP Timeout Limit? (CentOS with cPanel)

Tags: centos5, mysql

My server: CentOS 5.x, cPanel/WHM, PHP 5.3.6.

I am trying to import a large size of mysql data into a db with phpMyAdmin, the progress is terminated. It says:

[image]

Below, it also mentions that:

[image]

So it seems that failure dues to php timeout setting. 
(p.s I don't want to use the mysql spilt dump, don't want to upload time and time again, I just want a single one time dump)

Then I change the max_execution_time value to zero:

[image]

Saved and restarted apache and mysql. 
Then I dropped the db, started the dump in mysql again, still couldn't go through. Same result as before says Script timeout passed. ....

**What can I do? What setting should I change to make it happen? (I have root access)**

Thanks.

Comment: If the database size is large (more than several Megabytes), I recommend you to use command line tools like `mysqldump` and `mysql`. They are very much faster and efficient that using phpmyadmin for large DBs export and import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` in the `php.ini` file plus modifying `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;` in `config.inc.php` for phpMyAdmin should do the trick.